# Why are stars white?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, astronomy, thermal-radiation, stars

That is may be an easy question, but I am not a professional. The Sun is a star, and when I look at the Sun it is usually yellow. Why are stars in the sky at night white?

I suppose it could be due to their distance. What is the explanation?

Comment: Curious, I see the night stars as mostly comprised of red & blue stars.

Comment: More on stars colors: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5954/25301, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74844/25301, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66805/25301, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46500/25301

Comment: @KyleKanos It would be fairly unusual if your mesopic vision allowed you to discern the colour of any star fainter than first magnitude

Comment: I have presumed you are asking why stars appear white - which they do, despite having a wide variety of temperatures and spectra.

Comment: Also note that when you spot a particularly bright star, it's quite likely a planet.

Comment: The Sun appears yellow under a clear sky because of Raleigh scattering.  Look at an overcast cloudy sky and sunlight will appear with the white colour it actually has.

Comment: Somewhat related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137189/59023

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It has more to do with physiology of the eye rather than the spectrum of light produced by stars.

Stars emit light over the full range of visible wavelengths. Hot stars emit more blue/violet light, cool stars emit more red light. The Sun is relatively neutral in that regard, so does not have a strong colouration, but many other stars in the sky have temperatures as low as 3,000K (should appear reddish) to 20,000K or more (should be blueish).

However, light received by the eye has to be reasonably bright to trigger the colour sensitive cells (the cones). So whereas the Sun appears to be yellow(ish) (or to be more exact your eyes perceive the mix of wavelengths as yellowish), there are relatively few stars that are bright enough to look distinctly coloured. Betelgeuse is an example that most people see as reddish. Arcturus is distinctly orange (to me).

But fainter stars all appear white because they are mainly being seen by the rod cells in your eye, which are not very colour sensitive (and have no sensitivity to light at the extremes of red and blue). This is known as [scotopic vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotopic_vision).

APPENDIX: I have found a few interesting links that appear to confirm this line of argument. Firstly, one can [predict what stellar spectra would look like to the eye](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/) under conditions where the cone cells are operational. Here we can see that many stars would appear either pink (K-stars) through orange (M-stars). G-stars like the Sun are just off-white, whilst hot stars are distinctly blue (see also [here](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/colour/Tspectrum.html)).

These calculations do not include the effects of the Earth's atmosphere which preferentially absorb and scatter blue light. However, the effect of this on the colours cannot be that serious (it will have no effect at all on rod cells since they are not colour sensitive). Cone cells are sensitive over the range [450-650 nm](https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/PenetrantTest/Introduction/lightresponse.htm). The typical atmospheric *transmission* at zenith for these wavelengths ranges from 85% to 93% (see Fig.1 of [Burke et al. 2010](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...720..811B)), but would reduce to perhaps 70% to 85% for an object only 30 degrees above the horizon. Even at this low altitude, the *differential* effect is quite small. The colours of stars would not be changed by the atmosphere until they got quite close to the horizon.

**Stars would have different colours, ranging from pale blue through to an orangey-red, if they were bright enough to excite the eye's cone cells.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21974/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-jeffries-why-are-stars-white).

Comment: A related comment - I have seen the Northern Lights a couple of times when flying back from the US over the Atlantic, but it has never been bright enough to be colorful. OTOH I have seen pictures from airline seats of people who photographed it as being colorful (green and red), so I am not sure if that was the brightness, my eyes, or maybe higher senstivity of the camera used.

Comment: @MikeWise a big difference with the northern lights is that they are *strongly* coloured. The radiation observed is often in the form of one or two narrow spectral lines.

Comment: Which makes it all the more frustrating that the 2-3 times I saw them, they were white :)

Comment: @MikeWise It's normal that they look white. When I saw them for the first time, I wasn't even sure if that was a whitish spotlight shining into the sky (too faint to be light-polluted clouds, and with a non-typical shape for clouds). I was going to suppose that it was a spotlight, but then noticed that there were multiple of them at various directions from azimuth -45° to +45°. Knowing what shapes aurorae can have made me rush to my DSLR, and only that could confirm that these streaks were indeed green (and thus confirm their nature, aurora).

Answer (score 12):

Short answer:  Many of them are not.

Stars can be modeled as black-bodies.  That means that the spectrum of light that they emit depends on their temperature, and the color of a star can be described as its [Color Temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature). The color temperatures of stars can vary quite greatly, because stars have very different temperatures and emission spectras.  One of the things that you'll notice about color temperatures and blackbody radiation is that "white" is actually a pretty imprecise term.

With that in mind, different stars are categorized by their different [spectral types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_types), where stars of different spectral types prominently emit visible light in different noticeable wavelengths.

Some stars, such as[La Superba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Superba), [Betelgeuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betelgeuse), and [Antares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antares) are known for their noticeably red colors, even with the naked eye.

Other stars, like [Rigel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigel), [Fomalhaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fomalhaut), and [Vega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fomalhaut) have a bluish-white color.

La Superba is known as the reddest star that we've ever found, but it's too dim to be seen with the naked eye.  Every other star I mentioned above though, fall in the top 20 brightest stars.  For that reason, more light from these stars reach your eye, and differences in color are more easily seen (for reasons well explained in Rob's answer).  Even many stars which appear white in the naked eye usually have a non-white color when viewed in binoculars or a telescope.  [Albireo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albireo) is probably [the most brilliant example](http://www.albireovineyards.com/uploads/1/3/0/2/13028271/2582976_orig.jpg).

I would offer two concrete (although not very physical) reasons why most stars still appear white to you.
First, you may not be looking very closely.  I don't say this flippantly at all.  Before I started observing the night sky, I was unaware of the patterns and structure that exists.  I know people who don't even realize that the night sky changes throughout the night (and from month to month).  I really just say this to suggest that if all you ever give the night sky a casual glance, you'll fail to see the full detail.  But the more you observe, the more the patterns and detail begin to emerge.

Second, to build off Rob's answer, your eyes are actually pretty bad at figuring out color.  To illustrate this point, think of the last time you were in a low lighting environment.  You probably had a much easier time seeing shapes, and outlines of objects than you did seeing color of individual objects.  For dimmer stars, only a minuscule amount of their light arrives at your eyes, and it's just not enough for your eyes and brain to make an accurate determination of color.

Comment: Okay, but then why do we *perceive* most of them as being white, at least to the naked eye?

Comment: I will edit this evening to expand my answer.

Comment: We perceive most of them as being white, because most of the visible stars are white to whitish-blue. There are tons and tons of red dwarfs out there that aren't visible because frankly, red dwarfs are really dim. But there are also lots of red giants out there, and they're more obvious. On a clear winter night, you should go out into the country and find Orion. You will see a fair variety of colours in that constellation alone. So the other reason that you perceive them as all white is you just haven't been doing enough observing.

Comment: @DaveCoffman Updated.

Answer (score 7):

The sun is white. I've seen people say that it just looks yellow because the blue light is being scattered by the atmosphere. Since starlight is also scattered your question is still valid. But based on [these pictures](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&biw=1301&bih=657&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=sun%20in%20the%20sky&oq=sun%20in%20the%20sky&gs_l=img.3..0l10.59889.59889.0.60139.1.1.0.0.0.0.110.110.0j1.1.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.img..0.1.109.4TsHST12hpk), the sun still seems to look pretty white through our atmosphere. My guess is that, since you can safely look directly at a star, you learned their color through first-hand experience. You learn the color of the sun primarily from being told what color it is, and maybe from looking at it during sunrise and sunset, when there's more atmosphere and it's redder.

The color of stars in general is controlled by [blackbody radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#/media/File:PlanckianLocus.png). As something heats up, it starts of reddish, then it gets yellowish, then it gets whitish, then it gets bluish, but it's all pretty washed out and anything between 3000 and 10000 kelvins is going to look pretty white.

Comment: I think that the Sun is white only when it's overhead. Because when it is overhead, it has to travel the least distance due to which the atmosphere is not able to scatter the white light.

Comment: I did say that. "and maybe from looking at it during sunrise and sunset, when there's more atmosphere and it's redder." I imagine the stars near the horizon are also redder, but a lot harder to see so you might not notice them.

Comment: The Sun and stars are affected by the atmosphere in exactly the same way, so this is not the reason stars do not *appear* to be coloured. The answer is scotopic vision.

Comment: @AkshatTripathi the different colors of natural light is well known to photographers. You might pop into the photo.SE if you're interested in that.

Comment: This answer is relevant, because it points out that the expectation to see yellow stars is due to the Earth's atmosphere.  The last paragraph correctly answers the question.

Comment: @gerrit No absolutely it doesn't. The *proof* that this answer is wrong (by that I mean the last paragraph, which is what purports to answer the question) is that a few of the *brightest* stars do appear coloured (e.g Betelgeuse, Arcturus, Antares, Rigel), it is only the more numerous faint ones that do not. However, when you look at those faint stars through a telescope (increasing the intensity of the light reaching your retina), many of those stars *do* appear coloured. There are many famous examples as Sean correctly points out.

Comment: See http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/ for what colour stars would look like if they were bright enough.

Comment: Those photos are not a good proof of anything, because the pixel values from direct imaging of the sun in this manner are saturated, and therefore no longer an accurate measure of color (or intensity).

Comment: The sun itself is saturated, but the blooming is not. If the sun really was yellow, it would fade to yellow and then to sky blue, instead of fading directly to sky blue.

Answer (score 4):

Our sun is actually white. [Sun seen from space.](http://cdn.phys.org/newman/gfx/news/hires/2011/abrightsunan.jpg) It's just that when the sun rays enter the earth, our atmosphere scatters the white light resulting in different colors.

The reason why the Sun appears to be white sometimes is usually because it's directly overhead. Then the rays coming from the sun have to travel the least distance and hence encounter less and less atmosphere which is not enough to scatter the white light of the Sun.

Coming to other stars. Most stars in the night sky *appear* to be white when they really are not. Many of them are red, blue, green, orange etc. But because they are light years away from us, our eye is hardly ever able to distinguish the color and we see it as either white or slightly blue.

Comment: People don't know that they don't know what color the sun is. The idea that the sun is yellow is as well-known as that the sky is blue. They have no way of knowing to look it up, and telling them to look up more things isn't helpful. The best you can do is send everyone a link to a [list of common misconceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions).

Comment: Yeah, I know. When I mentioned the Rayleigh scattering's phenomenon, I was talking about the Sun, not the stars which appear in the night sky.

Comment: The atmosphere is still there at night! The Sun and stars are affected by the atmosphere in exactly the same way.

Comment: Right, because they are far away, our eyes are not able to distinguish their color.

Comment: The sun is massively, massively overexposed in the photograph you link, so that doesn't prove anything. Any object that's that overexposed looks white.

Comment: Just to be pedantic about the 2nd paragraph, the distance light travels from the sun to the observer is basically the same regardless of where the sun is in the sky. It is only the amount of atmosphere the light is travelling through that has changed significantly.

Comment: Actually, we *do* know what color the sun would be, without the atmospheric filtering: peachy pink. If you are in space you still don't see that because you use a dark sun visor. The spectrum is accurately known, and besides calculating the tristimulus values, you can create the same spectrum in a lab and see for yourself. Include "peachy pink" in search terms to find a reference.

Comment: @jdlugosz Wait, if it's peachy pink, then how come prism disperses the sunlight into seven colors? I thought that only white light is composed of seven colors...

Comment: @AkshatTripathi lookmupm [blackbody radiation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). It is not 7 colors, but a continuum, essentially an infinite number of different wavelenths. How our color perception works can be read in detail at [a favorite link](http://www.handprint.com/LS/CVS/color.html).

Comment: It is very easy to verify that the Sun is white.  Any cloudy sky will reveal that.